# echo an array number with a variable

Tags: php, arrays, vimeo

I have created an array from a json file and can call thumbnails/ titles just fine.

```
<?php
$file_contents = file_get_contents("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/username/videos.json");
    $data = json_decode($file_contents);
    $image= $data[0]->{'thumbnail_large'};
    $title= $data[1]->{'title'};
    ?>

    <?php
   echo '<img src="'.$image.'"/>';
       echo $title; 
    ?>
```

However I want to echo the array number with $image so that i dont have to create multiple variables i.e $image1 $image2 etc for each thumbnail or title.

below is a version of the above code were i used $num to try to illustrate what I mean.

```
<?php
    $file_contents = file_get_contents("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/olouali/videos.json");
    $data = json_decode($file_contents);
    $image[$num]= $data[$num]->{'thumbnail_large'};
    ?>

    <?php 
    echo '<img src="'.$image[$num].'"/>';
            ?>
```

I'm not sure if this is the right approach to what I'm trying to create as I'm still learning php.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$file_contents = file_get_contents("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/olouali/videos.json");
$data = json_decode($file_contents);

$count = count($data);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo '<img src="'.$data[$i]->{'thumbnail_large'}.'"/>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Once I've added this new code which variable is controlling the array number? $count, $data??